# Modal Close Animation

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

Can someone please help me with B3 modal animation using animate.css?
Check animate.css here: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

I have already included the 'bounceInLeft' when the modal opens and I want to use the 'bounceOutRight' when it closes.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shan12/25WHg/

html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#myModal').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
```

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following :

```
$("#myModal").one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function (e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.animationName == "bounceOutRight") {
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    $(".modal").remove();
  }
});

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#myModal').addClass('bounceOutRight');
  return e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rcarubbi/25WHg/33/)

Answer (score 0):

Its more like a work around.

```
var hideDelay = true;
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
  if (hideDelay) {
    $('.modal-content').removeClass('animated bounceInLeft').addClass('animated bounceOutRight');
    hideDelay = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      $('.modal-content').removeClass('animated bounceOutRight').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    }, 700);
    return false;
  }
  hideDelay = true;
  return true;
});
```

Check added animated class to **'.modal-content'** instead of **'#myModal'**.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/25WHg/43/